# IE css fix help needed. Rectangular box appears in dropdown

Tags: css

Please [check this page](http://girisoft.net/ie/).

You can see some css dropdowns in the right side.

In google chrome its working correctly

**But in IE i see some rectangular boxes**.

Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the select box within each styled `<div>` is visible. You can fix it by setting the opacity of each `<select>` to 0 in IE9, or using `filter:alpha(opacity = 0)` in older IEs

Comment: I tried your suggestion. But i don't see any changes.

Comment: this fixed it for me when I added the style in the developer toolbar..?

Answer (score 0):

Try to explicitly set the background color of `#unlockingp option` to transparent.

```
#unlockingp option {background-color:transparent}
```

For some reason the bg color seems to be set to `rgb(10, 110, 143)`, that is what the IE developer toolbar tells me.

Comment: I tried your suggestion too. But i'm not seeing any changes. :(

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using CSS PIE - http://css3pie.com/

It allows you to use CSS3 features in IE6-9 without breaking in other browsers. You can add rounded corners and even gradients using CSS PIE. The perks are you don't have to use images and hence wait for the images to load. PIE does all the heavy lifting for you.

If you need to add a gradient in your rectangular boxes, you can generate the gradients here and then copy the code in the right hand panel when you have the gradient of your choice - http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Additionally, you can use the Jquery plugin - http://www.verot.net/jquery_select_skin.htm - which helps skin select boxes. **Note:** The plugin doesn't work in IE6 but degrades gracefully.